# How to add progress bar in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am adding members into different tiles with csv file and i have lots of entries in the csv. I want to add the progress acitivty bar in my codes to see the progress

```
$csv = Import-Csv csv_file_path.csv
foreach ($addmember in $csv) { Add-TeamUser -GroupId $addmember.tilename -User $addmember.useridid -Role Member}
```

Comment: There's a cmdlet for that: [Write-Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use write-progress in get-filehash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367889/how-to-use-write-progress-in-get-filehash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify Avshalom's answer:

```
$csv = Import-Csv csv_file_path.csv
$i = 1
foreach ($addmember in $csv) {
    Add-TeamUser -GroupId $addmember.tilename -User $addmember.useridid -Role Member
    Write-Progress -Activity "Scanning Items" -Status "Items Scanned: $($csv.Count -$i) of $(($csv).Count)" -PercentComplete (($i / ($csv.Count)) * 100)
    $i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cmdlet `Write-Progress` see an example:

```
$i=1
$Items = 1..10000
foreach ($item in $Items)
{
Write-Progress -Activity "Scanning Items" `
-Status "Items Scanned: $($Items.Count -$i) of $(($Items).Count)" `
-PercentComplete (($i / ($Items.Count)) * 100)
$i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. should I put these codes after the second line?

Comment: No, integrate it as part of your loop